# How do I force a task cancellation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

Assume, there is a task containing the following actions approximately:

```
Task someTask = new Task(() => {

  while(!IsCancellationRequested) {

    Do_something_over_a_long_period_of_time();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    Do_something_over_a_long_period_of_time();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    Do_something_over_a_long_period_of_time();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
});
someTask.Start();
```

And there are pretty impatient users. They long to terminate my application immediately. They don't want to wait while long action is running.

I used to use the `Thread` class and was able to abort all my threads immediately with invoking the `Abort()` command.

How do I abort my tasks immediately?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @HadleyHope How would Background Worker solve his problem. It supports cancelation in similar way as Tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They long to terminate my application immediately. They dont want to wait while long action is running.

By default, Tasks run on the ThreadPool as background tasks. You can safely exit the application without bothering about background threads.

So as long as you want to quit your process there is no problem.

Note that Thread.Abort() was quick but not safe. Not even for a quitting application, but then it would seldom cause a real problem.

Comment: I don't think I'd say "there is no problem" - what if one of those background threads is half way through writing a file which the application will need next time it starts up?

Comment: I have forget about the ThreadPool and about the background tasks. It works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

You can't force a task to abort in an uncooperative manner. Aborting a thread in an uncontrolled way is unsafe, and thus deliberately unsupported.

You should make your `Do_something_over_a_long_period_of_time` calls cancellable instead (i.e. pass them the token, and make *them* check regularly too).

EDIT: As noted in another answer, you can kill the *application* just by making sure all the foreground threads have terminated. But you need to be aware that your tasks won't necessarily have had a chance to terminate *cleanly*. If they're doing things like writing files, you may well want to wait until the cancellation has been noticed, to avoid corrupting persisted state.

Comment: So if I spin up a new Task which just calls a single method GetDataThatRunsForTheNext40secs(), then there is no way to cancel the task immediately from the outside ? The results for such cancelled don't matter - but I'd like my CPU to be doing useful things as soon as possible. Thoughts ?

Comment: @Gishu: I don't know of any way which can do it *safely*, without the cooperation of the task in question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - by task, do you mean the new Task that I'm spawning OR do you mean the (possibly) third party work done by GetData.. method() that takes a long time to return ? The Task is written by me but the GetData method is not. Any links on doing this the right way - note: that my task isn't a loop where I can check a boolean to exit early. (i.e. the BackgroundWorker way).

Comment: @Gishu: Well, fundamentally the long-running GetData... method. If that doesn't provide any way of terminating it cleanly, then you have to choose between letting it run and wasting the effort (then ignoring the results), or aborting the thread and *hoping* that doesn't cause instability.

Comment: At the end of the day `Do_something_over_a_long_period_of_time` might be a 3rd-party library call which you cannot modify to be cooperatively cancel-able. Therefore to be able to forcibly cancel this sort of Task is still a legitimate real world requirement. Yes killing it's thread may or may not be safe, depending on what work the function is doing (I/O etc) but nevertheless there has to be a best approach to this other than "don't do it".

Comment: @Schneider: Well it depends on what you mean by "best" - if you think "just kill the thread and don't care if we lose customer data" is better than "don't implement a feature we can't implement safely" then yes, you can do that. Flippant language aside, sometimes that absolutely *is* the way forward. But if you're saying "There has to be a way of terminating arbitrary code safely" then I suspect that's wishful thinking rather than an assertion.

Comment: I agree arbitrary code can't be terminated safely. I have a specific scenario in mind: We are running a CPU-intensive mathematical "solver" which can take minutes to run. It simply crunches numbers, eventually returning a result, but does no I/O (although it may allocate unmanaged memory etc). We must be able to cancel this but we can't change the library. What do we do? Best solution I can think is separate _process_ per computation, or perhaps an AppDomain?

Comment: @Schneider: Separate process would definitely be cleaner; AppDomain *may* well be okay; to be honest I don't know enough about the details of AppDomain separation to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Suddenly, for the first time, I see a use for *nix `fork` :)